# Can i know how to import the database in mongoDB atlas?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I would like to know a suitable solution to import database in the momgoDB atlas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
# this cleans up the temp directory
    rm -rf /tmp/mongo-dump 

# this saves the dump of the ${db_name} database you have to the /tmp/mongo-dump directory
    mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://${user}:${pass}@${cluster-identifier}.mongodb.net/${db_name}?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --out=/tmp/mongo-dump

# this restores the ${db_name} database from the dump you created with previous script 
    mongorestore --uri="mongodb+srv://${user}:${pass}@${another-cluter-id}.mongodb.net/${db_name}?retryWrites=true" /tmp/mongo-dump
```